# Nodejs express routing : no styling if "/" is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have no idea how to phrase it(that's why google couldn't help me...) so let me give you an example.

If I go to my page [mypage.whatever/login](http://mypage.whatever/login), everything is fine.

But if I go to [mypage.whatever/login/](http://mypage.whatever/login/), the page has no styling. It only has HTML.

In my main node/express file I have `app.use("/login", login);`

In the login.js file I have :

`router.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("login", {title: "Login page"});
});`

How could I correct this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

Thanks to Manasov Daniel and jfriend00, I found out where the problem came from.

The stylesheet aren't included when I add a "/" because the routes get messed up.

For instance with a stylesheet like this

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/login.css">`

Instead of looking for `something/stylesheets/login.css`

The browser searches for `something/login/stylesheets/login.css`

Do you guys have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try this `app.use("/login/*", login);`

Comment: could you show content of 'login' template? I think problem is in stylesheet route.

Comment: What paths are you using for your CSS files in your HTML files?  Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The problem is indeed in the routes of the css files.
I edited the question, if you have an idea please let me know :)
@jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

When your style sheets are included with a path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/login.css">
```

Then, the browser treats them as relative paths and they are evaluated relative to the path of the current page.  That is rarely what you want for shared resources so you should probably change to use a leading slash like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/login.css">
```

---

The reason it works differently when you do or don't have a trailing slash is because when there is no trailing slash, then `/login` is treated as the filename and `/` is the path.  So, `stylesheets/login.css` would be combined with `/` and the result would be `/stylesheets/login.css` and it would work.

But, if you use `/login/`, then that is treated as the path and that path gets combined with your style sheet link to give you `/login/stylesheets/login.css` which does not work.

The answer is to always include a root path in your stylesheet links (e.g. something that starts with `/`).  Then, they will not be combined with the path of the page, only with the domain and port of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your main node/express file, you have:

```
app.use('/login', require('./your_file_path/login')); // login.js file path
```

And in the login.js file, you should have:

```
router.get("/login", function(req,res){
    res.render("login", {title: "Login page"});
});
```

Comment: I do have that, I forgot to include it sorry.

the "login" variable refers to var login = require("./routes/login");

Answer (score 0):

To answer the edit part :

adding a pre-slash to my css routes fixed the problem.

ie from href="something/myfile.css" to href="/something/myfile.css"

I don't really understand why though.

Comment: It's the difference between a relative path (`something/myfile.css`) and an absolute path (`/something/myfile.css`). A relative path starts at your current  location, for the question this will be `login`, while an absolute path starts at the app root directory.